# How to know total nodes in an elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-7

I have 3 nodes elasticsearch cluster. If more than one node goes down then I can easily check them manually. Suppose nodes in the cluster got increased then it will be difficult to check them manually. So, how can I get all the nodes(specifically name of the nodes) of the cluster even if they are down?

To get live/healthy nodes I hit the api endpoint:

`curl -X GET "hostname/ip:port/_cat/nodes?v&pretty"`

Is there any endpoint by using which I can get total nodes and unhealthy/down nodes in elasticsearch cluster?

I was trying to list all the nodes using `discovery.seed.hosts` present in `elasticsearch.yml` config file. But I don't know how to do it or is it the right approach or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any API to know about offline nodes. If your entire cluster is down or single node down, then Elastic doesn't provide any way to check the node's health. You need to depend on an external script or code or monitoring tool which will ping all your nodes and print status.

You can write a custom script which will call below API and it will return all the nodes which are available in the cluster. Once you have received response, you can filter out IP or hostname of the node and whichever are not coming in response you can consider it as down node.

```
GET _cat/nodes?format=json&filter_path=ip,name
```

Another option is to enable [cluster monitoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/monitor-elasticsearch-cluster.html) which will give you status of entire cluster but again it will show information about running node only.

Please check [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/offline-nodes-disappear-in-monitoring/136617/2) answer for how Kibana show offline node in Cluster Monitoring.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So, we can only list or count the nodes which are live or in healthy state right? Can you share some articles or resources related to the script?

And I have used the Kibana dashboard stack monitoring feature to monitor the es cluster, if there is no such api endpoint then how kibana is able to show offline/down nodes?

Comment: Please read [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/offline-nodes-disappear-in-monitoring/136617/2) answer for how Kibana show offline node. They have mentioned same approach which i have mentioned in answer like comparing list of nodes from monitoring response and cluster configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar Patel this will help.

Comment: FYI, on Kibana you have Stack Monitoring part, showing some basic info.

Comment: @ozgurozkanakdemirci He want to know about offline node which will never show on Kibana stack monitoring part. it will show only information about online node.